# Correct phrasing for points to improve and keep

Tags: phrases, idioms

I saw in a presentation that there's a specific idiom to use when presenting points to improve and things to keep doing.

Any catchy phrase that can describe it?

Edit: 
Maybe a use case will help. I need to display the results of an agile retrospective to upper management. The result was 3 good practices, and 3 bad practices. Isn't there an idiom to describe **both at once**? Internally we use 'Take & Break Points' with take being the positive practices.

Comment: Findings? Results? Talking Points?

Comment: @JonLarby this implies they are the same. I want to be clear about the categories

Answer (score 1):

Things which a person or organisation is doing right is [good practice](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/good%20practice): things which they are doing less well are *poor practice*; things they are doing really badly are [bad practice](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/good%20practice).

On [this website](http://www.anncrafttrust.org/safeguarding-guidelines-2014.php) the Ann Craft Trust define poor practice in relation to working with people with learning difficulties and compare it with abuse. They do not suggest that poor practice is, in itself, abuse but imply that poor practice can allow abuse to take place. Abuse, of course, is very bad practice.

Good practice is fairly easy to recognise, though it will vary from business sector to business sector. Just what constitutes poor or bad practice, however, will depend on the organisation's definitions, though there are some common factors like maintaining good customer relations.

Answer (score 0):

In the Agile software methodology there is a meeting held at the end of an iteration called a [retrospective](http://searchsoftwarequality.techtarget.com/definition/Agile-retrospective). In an attempt to focus on *continual improvement*, this is a *lessons learned* meeting that discusses what worked well and what didn't work well.

Not sure if this is what you saw, but it may give you some ideas.